# Log cat doesn't appear to be working for me

Tags: android

I have imported the library already. I'm not seeing any messages though in my screen.

```
final String temp = "temp";
int counter =0;
Log.v(temp, "counter is " +counter);
counter =20;
Log.v(temp," counter is " +counter);
```

Comment: Do you have USB Debugging enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a few things:

1) Set debuggable="true" in your android manifest.

First close and open eclipse. Then run in debug mode.

I usuall use

```
   Log.debug("classname", "counter is "+counter);
```

2) try running in debug mode and see what you get.

Also there is no need to import another logger.  Just use the one that comes with Android.

```
 import android.util.Log;
```

Another useful thing (for this an other issues) is to open window and goto installation directory of android sdk.  From there you can run adb kill-server and adb start-server etc.  there are other useful things with adb like adb devices tells you if the debugger sees a device or not. So put adb in your path.  I think its in the bin directory or something under the android sdk.

Comment: how do you run in debug mode?

Comment: right click the project in eclipe and run debug as instead of run as.

Comment: It will only run in debug if you change manifest and specifically run it in debug mode. This provides more feedback.  Debugging is super important.  Take the time to set a few breakpoints in the Activity files like onCreate and watch the debugger stop on a breakpoing.  Just right click a line number and you can set a breakpoint.  Then step thru. Save you thousands of hours believe me.

Comment: When I was in grad student told me I was my own worst enemy not using the debugger.  Most important advice I ever got and it took me years to recognize it.

Comment: I was able to use the eclipse debugger but not LogCat? I'm getting messages on my logcat from other phone programs just not the things I put in myself